# Stop displaying the microphone signal when button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that takes input and displays it on the screen using the tone.JS framework.

I have a toggle function to switch the microphone on and off. Turning the microphone on displays the number correctly. However, turning the switch off gives me output like the following:

6.135655369512991e-28,
6.135655369512991e-29,
6.135655369512991e-30,
6.135655369512991e-31,
and so on.

How do I get the function to reset to 0 (stop completely) when the toggle is switched off?
I would also like to stop logging the console when the toggle is checked as 'false' (off). How would I achieve this?

The function for the microphone toggle looks like this -

```
function micToggle() {
    if (micSwitch.checked === true) {
        mic.open();
    }
    else {
        mic.close();
        }
}
```

The function for the level meter (output) looks like this -

```
function drawMeter() {

    var level = meter.getLevel();
    // var absoluteLevel = Math.abs(level);
    level = Tone.dbToGain(level);

    // meterContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    // meterContext.fillStyle = meterGraident;
    // meterContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    // meterContext.fillStyle = "white";
    // meterContext.fillRect(canvasWidth * level, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    console.log(level);

    decibelMeter.innerText = level;
}
    window.setInterval(drawMeter, 700);
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you initialize the `mic` object.

Comment: @RobertGrossman var mic = new Tone.UserMedia();

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to use a global boolean, setting it to true when the mic is toggled open and false when toggled close.

However, this would still display the decibel level every so often. What you really want is to set the interval every time mic is toggled open and then clear it every time it is toggled close.

Your code might be modified to look like the following:

```
var interval;
function micToggle() {
    if (micSwitch.checked === true) {
        mic.open();
        interval = window.setInterval(drawMeter, 700);
    }
    else {
        mic.close();
        mic.dispose(); // to do cleanup
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Your code below without the `setInterval()` function would now look like:

```
function drawMeter() {

var level = meter.getLevel();
// var absoluteLevel = Math.abs(level);
level = Tone.dbToGain(level);

// meterContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
// meterContext.fillStyle = meterGraident;
// meterContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
// meterContext.fillStyle = "white";
// meterContext.fillRect(canvasWidth * level, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);


console.log(level);

decibelMeter.innerText = level;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Robert, that works perfectly to stop the console.log. But the number still increments on screen, so shows

-6.135655369512991e-28,
6.135655369512991e-29,
6.135655369512991e-30,
6.135655369512991e-31,

as before. Are you able to suggest any changes I could make to the code to reset the mic?

Comment: @Alfie Mitchell no problem! I added to my answer and that should address the problem more thoroughly.